# Git archive can't locate the tag

Tags: git

Git repo and client are running on MAC OSX 10.10

git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)

I'm trying to checkout specific files from git local repo using `git archive` command. I need to be able to get the files for specific tag. I'm trying this but getting error, with HEAD everything works fine:

```
git archive --format=zip --remote=ssh://git@<IP ADDR>/repos/<REPO NAME> 01236 REV.bin 01236.json > REV_YYYYMMDD_01236.zip
```

I'm getting error:

```
remote: fatal: no such ref: 01236
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `git ls-remote ssh://git@<IP ADDR>/repos/<REPO NAME>`? (with the real repo URL)

Comment: Does your remote repository actually contain either a tag or a branch named "01236", or a commit or tree for which "01236" is a unique prefix?

Comment: ComputerDruid thanks for push in the right direction! The build server didn't pushed correctly the local tag that was created for the commit to remote git. git ls-remote ssh://git@<IP ADDR>/repos/<REPO NAME> helped me to debug it, now everything works!